# Cannot create a file in flutter

Tags: flutter, filehandle

I have tried this code below but an empty folder i have found and still cannot create a file, but no errors found in the terminal.

here is the packages i have used :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
```

this is the codes to create the file, is there something wrong:

```
Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    
    Directory? appExtDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    
    String appExtPath = appExtDirectory.toString();
    
    print('$appExtPath');
    return appExtPath;
  }

  

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await getFilePath();
    
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<File> writeCounter() async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString("This is my demo text that will be saved to : counter.txt");
  }

  void saveFile() {
    writeCounter();
  }
```

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

Try `String appExtPath = appExtDirectory.path;`